# Electron disable cookies

Tags: cookies, electron

I was wondering if it's possible to enable/disable cookies within the chromium plugin browser for electron.

My application uses a third party authentication and renders a pop up window for it.  I want to disable the cookies when the user is authenticating and then re-enable it after its completes since i only care about the tokens. There are other reasons for this that I don't want to go into with the way the app is designed.

The application use https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/session.md.  It talks about how to add/get/delete cookies, but not how to disable/enable it.

Any advice appreciated,
Thanks,
D

Comment: sound like a feature of chromium, did you check the app or windows options? i think theres a flag can enable or disable cookies like other features

Comment: i'm not sure how you interface with the chromium aspect within electron...other then the browserWindow class which has no option that allows for this.

Comment: i think there's must be a way to do it, since in chrome we can enable or disable cookies, i'm checking the docs to make sure this.

Comment: Reading there's a feature on electron that allows us to use this flags, in your case i think you need to disable or enable `enable-account-consistency`  or `disable-account-consistency`. But i don't see support of electron. read [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md#supported-chrome-command-line-switches)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah...i don't see it in that document.....but how would you trigger this from the webview where your triggering a popup.  This would mean that you can only disable or enable cookies before the application starts the webview.  I don't think this allows for that....perhaps i need to rethink how i'm doing things.

Comment: yeah, i think you should rethink it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the third party auth providers require cookies to work correctly.  For example, some auth providers like live.com generate initial cookies before the user gets to the login page.  These cookies are required when the login button is clicked.

The question itself is moot at this point, but it's interesting why electron doesn't give the user the ability to disable/enable cookies though since it's just a shell for chromium which has the feature.  Perhaps the use case isn't high.